# Does the examination of utility nonprovisional patent applications last longer for first-time applicants than for other applicants?

Tags: uspto, timeline

I read on https://www.patenttrademarkblog.com/how-long-us-utility-patent-application-process/

> The USPTO is notorious for its backlog of examining utility nonprovisional patent applications. **First-time utility patent applicants** should expect the process to take several years.

That seems to imply that the examination of utility nonprovisional patent  applications last longer for first-time applicants than for other applicants, which I had never heard of.

Does the examination of utility nonprovisional patent applications last longer for first-time applicants than for other applicants? The page doesn't back up their claims.

Answer (score 2):

Although it wouldn't surprise me that first time applicants take a bit longer because of unfamiliarity with the process, I don't read that quote as suggesting it is due to their status at all. What I think is being pointed out is that the process takes a long time and first time applicants may not be aware of this. For my own patents (and I have quite a few) it wasn't uncommon for it to take three years to get a patent granted.

In any case, it might be an interesting question to answer definitively and I would guess that the data exists somewhere for someone inclined to check. Unfortunately, that person is not me.

Answer (score 2):

The linked article has a lot of good information about patent pendency and none of even hints at first time filers having higher pendencies. I think you are misreading it.

I do not think first time applicants wait any longer than other applicants although more sophisticated applicants might spend the money for expedited examination and know about free expediting due to age.

A chart from the blog [PatentlyO](https://patentlyo.com/patent/2018/02/patent-pendency-snapshot.html) from a few years ago shows a median of about 25 months from the filing of a non provisional utility application. The linked article links to similar information at the USPTO.

[image]